# Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException No message Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

This is doing my head in. I'm getting this error when trying to login from a form:

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \
>
> MethodNotAllowedHttpException
>
> No message

LoginController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    protected $username = 'username';
    protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';
    protected $guard = 'web';
    public function getLogin()
    {
        if (Auth::guard('web')->check())
        {
            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        }
        return view('login');
    }
    public function postLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $auth = Auth::guard('web')->attempt(['username' => $request->username, 'password' => $request->password, 'active' => 1]);
        if ($auth)
        {
            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        }
        return redirect()->route('/');
    }
    public function getLogout()
    {
        Auth::guard('web')->logout();
        return redirect()->route('/');
    }
}
```

The following route when i submit a form is working fine.

```
Route::get('/', ['as' => '/', 'uses' => 'LoginController@getLogin']);
Route::get('/login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'LoginController@getLogin']);

Route::group(['middleware' => ['autheticates', 'roles']], function (){
    Route::get('/logout', ['as' => 'logout', 'uses' => 'LoginController@getLogout']);
    Route::get('/dashboard', ['as' => 'dashboard', 'uses' => 'DashboardController@dashboard']);
});
```

Middleware/Autheticates.php

```
class Autheticates
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = 'web')
    {
        if (!Auth::guard($guard)->check())
        {
            return redirect()->route('/');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Middleware/Roles.php

```
class Roles
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $roles = $this->getRequiredRoleForRoute($request->route());
        if ($request->user()->hasRole($roles) || $roles){
            return $next($request);
        }
        return redirect()->route('noPermissions');
    }
    private function getRequiredRoleForRoute($route)
    {
        $actions = $route->getAction();
        return isset($actions['roles']) ? $actions['roles'] : null;
    }
}
```

login.blade.php

```
<form class="login-form" action="{{ route('login') }}" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="login-wrap">
        <p class="login-img"><i class="icon_lock_alt"></i></p>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon_profile"></i></span>
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" autofocus>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon_key_alt"></i></span>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
            <span class="pull-right"> <a href="#"> Forgot Password?</a></span>
        </label>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>
        <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block" type="reset">Signup</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

[image: Error Image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Error in the route you've defined. Its `get` and should change to `post`

change this

```
Route::get('/login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'LoginController@getLogin']);
```

to this

```
Route::post('/login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'LoginController@getLogin']);
```

---

```
action="{{ route('login') }}" # form Submit action
```

Comment: Oh - i do not see it, : )

Comment: When your form requesting post and route define as get, it will throw this http error

Comment: When I login It Should go to dashboard.

Comment: define redirect on success

Answer (score 3):

```
Route::post('/', 'PostController@index');

Route::post('/posts/create', 'PostController@create');

Route::post('/posts', 'PostController@store');
```

Post or get..if u pass post value than use `post`.

Answer (score 2):

your answer of the route should be

```
Route::post('/login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'LoginController@getLogin']);
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem appears only if you forget attached method on your form or error in Route method.

So be sure you added method POST/GET in your form. And don't forget make matching route.

```
<form method="POST">
```

If your form method is post. make post route like this.

```
Route::post();
```

I hope you understand the method define. If you're facing problem, comment below.