# Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException on laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

I Have tried to create a login page in Laravel 5.6 it shows the following error

**Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException**

I have used the POST method for the routing but the server shows the same error
 screenshot of the same is added.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEFSf.png)

The code of view

```
    <body>
    <div class="data-head">
        {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'login')) }}
        <p class="col-md-12">
            <h5 class="login-head">Login</h5>
        </p>
        <p>
            {{ $email_err }}
        </p>
        <p class="col-md-10 col-md-move">
            {{ Form::label('email', 'E-Mail Address', array('class' => 'awesome')) }}
            {{ Form::text('email','', array('placeholder' => 'yourname@example.com', 'class' => 'form-control')) }}
        </p>
        <p class="col-md-10 col-md-move">
            {{ Form::label('password', 'Password', array('class' => 'awesome')) }}
            {{ Form::password('password', array('placeholder' => 'Password', 'class' => 'form-control')) }}
        </p>
        <p class="col-md-10 col-md-move">
            <a href="forget" class="link-forget">Forget Password ? </a>
            {{ Form::submit('Login', array('class' => 'btn btn-info')) }}
        </p>

    </div>
</body>
```

Route file:

```
    Route::post('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
    });
    Route::post('register',function(){
        return view('login');
    });
    Route::post('login', 'LoginController@loginProcess');

The controller code

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Hash;

    class LoginController extends Controller
    {
        public function loginProcess(Request $request)
        {
            $email_err="";
            $password_err="";
            $pass="";
            $email = $request->input('email');
            $password = $request->input('password');
            $pass=DB::table('login')->where('email', $email)->value('password');
            if($pass=="")
            {
                $email_err="Non Registred User";
                return view('login',['email_error' => $email_err]);
            }
            if(Hash::check($password,$pass))
            {
                echo "Login Successs";
            }
            else
            {
                $password_err="Invalid Password";
            }

        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no CSRF token in your form.

Comment: is that mandatory ?

Comment: yes it is mandatory, use `{{csrf_token()}}` in your form

Comment: It is used there in meta tag     <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />

Comment: @RaymondThomas that meta tag doesn't have to do with how the form functions in anyway  ... sidenote, might want to close the form

Comment: CSRF token is added by default while creating a form

Comment: define method in your form {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'login', 'method' => 'post')) }}

Comment: why are all these routes POST routes? GET is used for a specific reason, to GET stuff. POST is used for ... posting stuff. If you want to get a view, why would it be a POST request?

Comment: At initial stage it was get I've changed them to post after reading the article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48225095/symfony-component-httpkernel-exception-methodnotallowedhttpexception-no

Answer (score 0):

You need to change code of view like below,

```
<body>
    <div class="data-head">
        {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'login','method' => 'post')) }}
        <p class="col-md-12">
            <h5 class="login-head">Login</h5>
        </p>
        <p>
            {{ $email_err }}
        </p>
        <p class="col-md-10 col-md-move">
            {{ Form::label('email', 'E-Mail Address', array('class' => 'awesome')) }}
            {{ Form::text('email','', array('placeholder' => 'yourname@example.com', 'class' => 'form-control')) }}
        </p>
        <p class="col-md-10 col-md-move">
            {{ Form::label('password', 'Password', array('class' => 'awesome')) }}
            {{ Form::password('password', array('placeholder' => 'Password', 'class' => 'form-control')) }}
        </p>
        <p class="col-md-10 col-md-move">
            <a href="forget" class="link-forget">Forget Password ? </a>
            {{ Form::submit('Login', array('class' => 'btn btn-info')) }}
        </p>

    </div>
</body>
```

You just need to provide method type in `Form::open()` facade like `'method'=>'post'` by default it is `GET`

Comment: No, it defaults to `post` "By default, a POST method will be assumed; however, you are free to specify another method:"

Comment: That is what understand from the documentation of Laravel 5.6

Comment: This package (Html Form Builder) isn't from Laravel .. it is a 3rd party package, so its not in those docs  ... i suppose you mean an actual html form and how browsers handle html when the method isn't defined?

Comment: You mean Htmlcollective ?

Comment: laravelcollective maintains the html and form package